# why do i always get redirected to "/" if i make GET request to "/sell" with http status code 302?

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest

IF i am not logged in and make "GET" request to "/sell" i am redirected to "/user/login" which is working accordingly.But if i am logged in and  i make GET request to "/sell" i am always redirected to
"/" i.e. homepage instead of "/sell" page.so what should i do to only access "/sell" page if i am logged in?.Here are the code snippets you may probably need. Please let me know if u need anything else. Thank you in advance.

/routes/sell.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}); 
const Product = require('../models/product');


router.get('/sell', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('sell',{title: 'Home|Sell', success: req.session.success,  errors: req.session.errors, csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
    req.session.success = null;
    req.session.errors = null;
})



router.post('/book_upload', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    req.check('name')
     .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Name must be of 3 characters long.')
     .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/).withMessage('Name must be alphabetic.');
    req.check('phone')
     .isLength({min:10,max:10}).withMessage('Phone number must be of 10 digits.');
    req.check('book_name')
     .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Book Name must be of 3 characters long.')
     .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/).withMessage('Book Name must be alphabetic.');
    req.check('book_price')
     .isNumeric().withMessage('Price must be numeric.');
    req.check('description')
     .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Description must be of 3 characters long.')
     .matches(/^[<A-Za-z0-9></A-Za-z0-9>\s]+$/).withMessage('Please write appropriate description.')
    req.check('faculty')
     .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('Faculty must be of 3 characters long.')
     .matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/).withMessage('Faculty must be alphabetic.')

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors){
        req.session.errors = errors;
        req.session.success = false;
    } else {
        req.session.success = true;

        var item = {
            name: req.body.name,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            book_name: req.body.phone,
            book_price: req.body.price,
            description: req.body.description,
            faculty: req.body.faculty
        };
       var data = new Product(item);
       data.save();
    }
    res.redirect('/sell');
})


function isLoggedIn (req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    req.flash('error', 'Please Login to Continue')
    res.redirect('/user/login');
}


module.exports = router;
```

and app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var validator = require('express-validator');
// var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@firstdatabase-ytrfr.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
  .then(()=>console.log('Connected to the database'))
  .catch(err=> console.log('could not connect.',err.message))



// passport
require('./config/passport');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var sellRouter = require('./routes/sell');
var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(validator());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'blahblah',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}))
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
})

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);
app.use('/', sellRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and sell.hbs

```
<section class="my_account_area pt--80 pb--55 bg--white">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
                    <div class="my__account__wrapper">
                        {{# if success}}
                            <section class="success">
                                <h2>Form submitted!</h2>
                            </section>
                        {{else}}
                        {{# if errors}}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <section class="errors">
                                    <ul>
                                        {{# each errors}}
                                            <li>{{ this.msg }}</li>
                                        {{/each}}
                                    </ul> 
                                </section>
                            </div>   
                         {{/if}}
                        <h3 class="account__title">Fill Up the Information of Book</h3>
                        <form action="/book_upload" method="post">
                            <div class="account__form">
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Your Name <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Phone No. <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Name of book <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Price of Book<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="book_price" name="book_price">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Description of Book<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder="e.g. To study in 1st year 1st part">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input__box">
                                    <label>Faculty<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="faculty" name="faculty">
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
                                <div class="form__btn">
                                    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {{/if}}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You could try moving your app.use for sellRouter few lines up, if that fixes the problem, then you know that your index or user router catches the request instead of intended sellRouter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.
Hence, change the order of

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);
app.use('/', sellRouter);
```

to

```
app.use('/', sellRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);
```

It will work.

Comment: thank you :) @taurus. That fixed. Just out of curiosity how long did it take you to reach this level like knowing solutions to problems in Node js?

Comment: could u explain me the answer,please? @taurus